# Why the R.Java file's logo is changed and now is not recognising the layout's ids?

Tags: android, r.java-file

I have tried everything to clean up the project, but the reference to layouts also exists in the R.java file but they are not recognised, and strangely enough the R.java's logo has changed, I have attached the image below.

I would really appreciate if someone could help me on that.

Many thanks in advance :-)
[image]

Answer (score 1):

1) Make sure you have no problems (Problems view) in your XML layouts.

2) Delete the **/bin** and **/gen** folders inside your project, then run **Project** -> **Clean** -> for your project.

Comment: great it looks normal now, but none of my java file can recognise anything from the alyouts also R has listed all of them, do you know what should I do ? thanks

Comment: check you last changes you made in your xml files, that does prevent the creation of a valid r.java file

Comment: be sure that you import the "your.project.package.R" file, not "android.R"

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the hollow J means that your file is excluded from the build path.
[Eclipse autocomplete not working in some Java files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2390371/eclipse-autocomplete-not-working-in-some-java-files)
Check to see if it is.

You could also try outright deleting R.java, it's automatically generated anyways, so it will come back.