# Why are classes kept in jars added via custom classpath container not available for code completion?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-jdt

What is necessary to get classes provided via custom classpath container visible in the code completion?

I have successfully implemented a custom classpath container, that adds libraries to a project. It adds all jars in a specific folder to the build path unless there is a project with the same name in the workspace, in that case the project is referenced.

Now this obviously seems to work, when I refer to a class from one of those jars, the code compiles, but I do not see the class in the code completion suggestions. When I have the correct project in my workspace, then I see such a class in the code completion.

I have done the following steps to reach this, while I was partly considering a [tutorial from IBM](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/tutorials/os-eclipse-classpath/):

- Implement ClasspathContainerInitializer
- Implement ClasspathContainerPreferencePage for additional configuration
- Implement IClasspathContainer

When I have added the container to a project I see the jars in the packages explorer as I expected it. (Jar there only if no corresponding project is available, Logging shows expected results)

I can use classes from jars integrated via classpath container without compiler errors, they are just not available for code completion and in Quick Fixes to add the right import. So I guess I maybe just miss contributing to some extension point.

Comment: I haven't worked with custom classpath containers, yet. But I think the `javaCompletionProposalComputer` might be a good start. The coderecommenders project has an example of usage: http://git.eclipse.org/c/recommenders/org.eclipse.recommenders.git/tree/plugins/org.eclipse.recommenders.completion.rcp.subwords2/src/org/eclipse/recommenders/internal/completion/rcp/subwords2/AssignmentVarnameMatchCompletionProposalComputer.java?id=865e3995df5a72df6e5b9fcd58aa9f92a3fcc359

Comment: you are using RAD / eclipse?

Comment: @Calon I will have a look into your suggestion. Maybe this will be of help.

Comment: @KalpeshSoni Yes, I use Eclipse.

Comment: This may help, even though it does not directly address the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2390371/eclipse-autocomplete-not-working-in-some-java-files

Comment: A deleted answer suggested peeking into the m2 sources for further advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer basically is: You do not need to do anything more than implementing the three parts. But you have to do it the right way.

The *ClasspathContainerPreferencePage* to prepare the container for adding it to the project.

The *ClasspathContainer* as entity getting added to the project. For this one it is really important to implement all needed methods right. For me the problem was that I returned a wrong constant value in the method *getKind()*. Instead of returning *IClasspathEntry.CPE_CONTAINER* I just needed to use *IClasspathContainer.K_APPLICATION* and the code completion worked out of the box:

```
public int getKind() {
    return IClasspathContainer.K_APPLICATION;
}
```

And finally a *ClasspathContainerInitializer* for preparing and updating the container.

Answer (score 0):

I use Eclipse Luna and Eclipse does autocomplete code even from custom external JARs. You should consider upgrading to Luna if you haven't already and see it solves your problem

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Sorry @Hamad, I would have commented if I had enough reputation.